# Graphics.CopyFromScreen is not working on remote desktop on win 7

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

```
var screenWidth = (int)SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
var screenHeight = (int)SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
var screenshot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
{
    // snip wanted area
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenshot.Size);

}
```

I am using above code to save the bitmap file before I print it. It works fine but when I remote into win7 machine and try to print it, it returns the desktop of remote instead of my screen.

Any suggestion would be help full.

Comment: It will return the desktop of the screen that it is running on.

Comment: @Mody disk : this is working perfectly fine in win8.

Comment: When you remote into Win7, are you running the program on your machine, or the win7 machine?

Comment: @Mody disk : I have a deployment package which I run on this windows 7 machine and than when I run my program on this remoted win7 machine, it only take the window as snapshot with the splash image of my application other than the current screen of it.